# Determine running programs using batch file and close them

Tags: batch-file

I'm learning how to make batch files and I would like to know if it is possible to make a batch file that would determine if you have any running programs in your desktop and know what programs are running in there and close all of them. Thank you very much...

Comment: yes, something like that.

Comment: I would like to close all those running programs :) @npocmaka

Comment: Close all running programs? Or close specified ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

cd c:\windows\System32
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1" %%i in ('TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME eq %userdomain%\%username%" /FI "STATUS eq running"') do (
if not "%%i"=="svchost.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="explorer.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="tasklist.exe" (
echo.
taskkill /f /im "%%i" 
echo.
)
)
)
)
)
pause
```

This will kill all processes that are running except a couple important ones.

Comment: Whoa... it worked! thanks a lot man. now I have to study how and why it works.  @MadsTheMan